# Accessing Local Kafka from within Services deployed in Local Docker For Mac (incl. Kubernetes extension)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, docker-for-mac

- I'm working locally on OSX.
- I'm using Kafka and zookeeper in local mode. Meaning Zookeeper from my Kafka installation. One node cluster.
- Both work on the loopback localhost `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181`
- My `/etc/host` looks as follows:

  ```
   127.0.0.1         localhost MaatPro.local  
   255.255.255.255   broadcasthost  
   ::1               localhost MaatPro.local  
   fe80::1%lo0       localhost MaatPro.local
  ```
- I have docker for Mac set on my machine, with the Kubernetes extension.

**My scenario**

I have an Akka-stream micro-service dockerized, that reads data from an external database and write it in a Kafka topic. It uses as bootstrap server `"localhost:9092"`.

**Issue**

When I run my service on my machine directly (e.g. command line or from within Intellij) everything works fine. When I run it on my Local Docker or Kubernetes I get the following error:

`(o.a.k.clients.NetworkClient) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 could not be established. The broker may not be available.`

With Kubernetes I build the following YAML File to deploy my pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: fetcher
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
   - image: entellectextractorsfetchers:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
     name: fetcher
```

I took the precaution to set **hostNetwork: true**

With Docker daemon directly I originally tried to set the network as host too but discovered that this does not work with Docker for Mac. Hence, I abandoned that route. I understood that it has to do with virtualization.

1. Does the virtualization issue that happens with docker is actually the same as my local Kubernetes? Basically, the host network is the virtual machine and not my mac?
2. I try to change my code and add as a bootstrap server the following address: **host.docker.internal** as per the documentation. But the problem persists. Is the fundamental problem the fact that I am working on a loopback address? Shall I work on my network address indeed? To which address does host.docker.internal point to? How can I make it work with the loopback address? If I'm completely off, any idea of what I need to implement to get this working?

Comment: See if this makes sense for your use case. https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/. Then try Kafka without k8s at first

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @cricket_007 guidance [Kafka Listeners - Explained](http://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained) and the many read I have had here and there over this issue, including the official docker documentation [I Want to connect from a container to a servicer on the host](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

I came up with the following solution.

I added the following to my default local kafka configuration (i.e. server.properties)

> ```
> listeners=EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
> listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
> advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092,EXTERNAL://docker.for.mac.localhost:19092
> inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
> ```

In fact External here, is ***expected*** to be the ***docker network***. This config is only for my OSX machine for my local development purpose. I do not expect people connecting to my laptop to use my local kafka hence i can use `EXTERNAL://docker.for.mac.localhost:19092.` This is what is advertised to my container in docker/kube. From within that network, docker.for.mac.localhost is reachable.

*Note this would probably not work with Minikube. This is specific to Docker For Mac. The kubernetes that I run on my machine is the one coming with docker for mac and not minikube.*

Finally in my code i use both in a list

```
"localhost:9092, docker.for.mac.localhost:19092"
```

I use typeSafe config, so that in prod, this is erased by the env variable. When the env variable is not specified, this is what is used. When i run my micro-service from Intellij `localhost:9092` is used. That’s because In that case, i am in the same network as my kafka/zookeeper in my machine. However when I run the same micro-service from docker/kube `docker.for.mac.localhost:19092` is used.

**Answers to the side questions I had**

1. **Yes. Docker for Mac use HyperKit as a lightweight virtual machine, running a linux on it, and Docker Engine is ran on it**. The Docker for MAC Kubernetes extension is basically about running kubernetes cluster Services/infrastructure as containers in the docker daemon. [Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment) . In other words, the host is hyperkit and not osx. But as the above doc explain, Docker for Mac implementation is all about making it appear to the user as if there were no virtualization involve between OSX and Docker.
2. - **Connecting to the host using loopback address is an issue that has not been solved.** I'm not even sure that it works perfect even if the host is Linux. Not sure, might have been resolved at this point. Nonetheless, it would require to run an image by stating that the container or the pod in the case of kube are on the host network. But in docker for mac, that functionality will never work based on my readings online. Hence the solution of using **docker.for.mac.localhost** or **host.docker.internal**, that Docker for Mac did set up to refer to the mac host and not the hyperkit host.
   - **host.docker.internal** and **docker.for.mac.localhost** are one of the same and the late recommendation at this point is host.docker.internal. This being said, this address did not originally work for me because my Kafka Set up was not good. It is worth readying @criket_007 link to understand that well http://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained.

Comment: By the way, `advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092` should actually be the internal service name/IP of that pod/Kafka container. You'd only notice issues with that config if you had more than one broker, though, since it's mostly used for replication

Comment: I am not fully sure to understand can you explain. My Kafka  and zookeeper are not in kubernetes at all. They are on my local machine, that is on the local network of my machine. Docker/kubernetes is on it’s on network within my machine, as per docker/kube process. So to me the external network to Kafka/zookeeper network, is docket/kube. Hence I do not completely understand your comment. Could you clarify it ?

Comment: What I have in my container/pod is an akka-stream micro-service. That service connect to Kafka, which is outside of my kubernetes, albeit on my machine.

Comment: Oh, so if Kafka and Zookeeper are not on Kubernetes, then I don't think you needed to setup protocol mappers at all. The only listener you needed was `EXTERNAL://docker.for.mac.localhost:19092`... Anyway, my point was that having a listener as `127.0.0.1` would make each connecting client only connect to itself, not the actual external server, which again only applies for multiple brokers (even when you have one machine)

Comment: Understood. Just for the record, for the reader of the response, I did set up that protocol mapper because i have to cases, running my application from within intellij, when I start my dev with debug, and running from within a container when i test the overall behavior before pushing out. The former means i am on my local machine network, while the later means i am on the docker network. Hence I need both in development mode.

Comment: Understood. Just for the record, for the reader of the response, I did set up that protocol mapper because I have 2 cases: (i) running my application from within intellij, when I start my dev with debug,(ii) and running from within a container when i test the overall behavior before pushing on our cloud infrastructure. The former means i am on my local machine network, while the later means i am on the docker network. Hence I need both in development mode

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I just wanted to add a little hack that allowed me to have a single port (9092) between my local machine and Docker containers. That way I didn't need to define a second port.

1) Edit `/etc/hosts` and add `127.0.0.1   host.docker.internal`
2) In `server.properties`, replace the lines you list with `listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.docker.internal:9092`

What this does is allow Docker to talk over `host.docker.internal`. And on the local machine, the listener with `host.docker.internal` gets mapped to `127.0.0.1` outside of Docker/Kafka because of `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

Following @MaatDeamon approach I only did the following and it worked for me.

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

And in your application config properties

```
localhost:9092,host.docker.internal:9092
```